# Anacondaをインストールしたが、開くことができない

Tags: python, anaconda

自分のPCにあるAnacondaをPCシステム設定上の「アプリと機能」より一旦アンインストールし、
再インストールを行いました。
インストール自体は完了しますが、その後、anaconda promptもNavigaterもすべて起動しません。

anacondaの保存場所から直接Anaconda_Navigater.exeも実行してみましたが、
起動しませんでした。

何度か、アンインストール＆インストールを繰り返しましたが解決しません。

何か原因や解決策が思い当たる方がいらっしゃいましたら、
ご助言いただけないでしょうか。よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 「アプリと機能」だとWindowsのようですが、そうしたOSの種類/版数、インストール時のオプション指定、インストール先といった情報を追記した方が回答や助言を得やすいでしょう。例えばこれらの記事が参考になるかも。[WindowsにAnaconda3のインストールする際のメモ](https://qiita.com/mainichinemui/items/d4c469d0c34c9a866d1f), [Anacondaをインストール](https://sugizo.info/2020/03/25/1498/), [Windows(M.S.)にPython3 (Anaconda3) を導入する（7つの罠）](https://qiita.com/kaizen_nagoya/items/7bfd7ecdc4e8edcbd679) あと今も適用されるか不明ですが、ユーザー名やフォルダ名に全角文字が含まれているとか、空白が含まれているのに考慮していないとかありませんか？ それからアンインストール時にフォルダやファイルの残骸があれば、すべて削除しておくとかした方が良いでしょう。

Comment: こんな記事があるようですが。[Anacoda Navigatorが立ち上がらなくなった](https://qiita.com/asobinin_kinsan/items/21982509b7652375abf0)